# correct subquery in sum function syntax error

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a subquery like

```
Select id, 
       sum(select fran_payment.amount 
           from fran_payment 
           where fran_payment.fran_id = id) as paid,
       sum(select purchase.commission_amount 
           from purchase 
           where purchase.fran_id = id) as commission
from franchiese;
```

It's giving me syntax error near select fran_payment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't sum over a query.
You must specify a column to sum over inside a query and this sum will be returned:

```
Select f.id, 
       (
         select sum(fran_payment.amount) 
         from fran_payment 
         where fran_payment.fran_id = f.id
       ) as paid,
       (
         select sum(purchase.commission_amount) 
         from purchase 
         where purchase.fran_id = f.id
       ) as commission
from franchiese as f;
```

Comment: I should have had more coffee before posting... here's a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=016e730e2be41bd9df6aa3b12084580d) for your query if you want it.